# How to access the value of username from htpasswd file using python script

Tags: python

I have created a username/ password in htpasswd file. In my python script file I would like to access the username value for further processing. How do I achieve that? I am using Linux OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The htpasswd format is `:", something that isn't terribly difficult to parse. Simply go through line by line and split on a colon, taking the first value:

```
usernames = []
with open("passwdfile") as htpwd:
    for line in htpwd.readlines():
        username, pwd = line.split(":")
        usernames.append(username)
```

Or more consisely:

```
with open("passwdfile") as htpwd:
    usernames = [line.split(":")[0] for line in htpwd.readlines()]
```

Comment: IT was so cool, maybe sometimes ;) all work and no play... :P